# Designing loots for chests

Tags: single-player

Let's say we have a game, with enemies you fight, items to get and also chests to find and loot. Imagine a RPG game if you will.
We also have a table with x items that the player can loot from these mentioned chests. Some of these items are "one drop only", while others can drop more than one time. We might set that as a variable in the table.
Now to the question: **When would you scatter the items in the table to the chests?**

- Would you do this as soon as the level loads?
- Would you do a lookup when the player opened a chest?

As far as I see it, if you scatter the items when the level starts, the player could miss a unique item, if the player skipped that specific chest containing that unique one-time-only item.
But, if you do a lookup when the player opens a chest, the player does not need to worry (if the player knew exactly how it was coded) about actually missing unique items.
How would you handle this design wise? Is it ok for players to miss unique items for being lazy/bad/unlucky? Or, do we always want the player to be able to get just about all the items in this table at one point?
Which way would you prefer as a dev? Which way would you prefer as a player? Have I missed an important factor, a third way to handle it, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My view: if you generate on chest open this will induce save scrimming (spelling?) and people re-loading saves for better loot unless it's MMO. If you do it on a per-level basis, on the other hand, you risk people missing cool loot due to (P)RNG screw ups and missed drop chances. Neither is terribly optimal IMO.
As a single player, story based and not random-generated loot developer, I personally prefer pre-set loot in most cases with minor variance cast on 'chapter' initialization (removed from level loads but still playthrough specific) states which are flipped, i.e. Item1 always appears somewhere, the question becomes is it in Part I, Part II, or Part III. I can also include minor variance in scenes based on the same RNG cast, making the game world seem less fixed, even if you reload prior to starting a new 'part' - whatever that mean in context, and parts for different 'types' of items may be cast at various points which are not advertised to the player but are internally consistent.
Seen from a practical perspective, my motivation is to ensure the player will (probably) run across all the items of type X if they do the appropriate quests/missions and access the thematically relevant content. At the same time, every playthrough is a bit different, because where items drop - both in a thematic 'set' progression and in general timeline progression - will influence how the character plays, but only within a certain spectrum.
This isn't a perfect system, to be honest, but when playing my own games (assuming someone like me, who knows where all the loot can be), it's incredibly annoying to NOT get an item just because a stupid RNG roll screwed me over. I prefer to walk over a trigger point for a specific encounter 10 times hoping for the respective outcome than to bungle around, looting randomly, and not getting what I want despite hours spent trying to perfect my character.
My philosophy is to allow a player who wants X and knows how to get X to get X reliably within the scope of a sub-progression, but not on a per level (or per-encounter) basis. This generally only works in SP games however. If you're going for something MP or group-centric, this will turn out badly.